# Synonyms for 'the use of'?

Tags: grammar, synonyms

I need synonyms for the word 'the use of' in my sentence.

> Also, the use of commonly available solutions contributed to cost
>   reduction.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: One perfectly good substitution would be *nothing at all*. Whatever these "commonly available solutions" are, they can only contribute to something if they're actually *used*, so there's no need to specify that.

Comment: What you mean to say, apparently, is that (1) somebody used commonly available solutions, and (2) that reduced the cost. Two sentences for the price of one, a good solution right there. Or you can nominalize _use_ into _the use of_, as you did. But why not just use a gerund? _Using commonly available solutions contributed to cost reduction._

Comment: @FumbleFingers - and think of how removing three words from the sentence cuts costs!  It is even topical!

Comment: @Oldcat: The economics of the modern world are sometimes counterintuitive. Note that [smart electricity meters can figure out which movie you're watching](http://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2012/01/08/28c3-smart-meter-hacking-can-disclose-which-tv-shows-and-movies-you-watch/). I'm guessing that's because dimmer pixels use less juice. My current display is black text on white background, so it should use less juice if it shows more words. If everyone in the whole world were viewing OP's text, switching to my shorter version might actually cost a significant amount more!

Answer (score 2):

**[employing](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/employing)**: making use of  (an instrument, means, etc.); using.